# Java Exception Stacktrace Not Printing

Tags: java, logging, exception, log4j

I have the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;
public void myMethod() {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)); // prints "java.lang.NullPointerException"
        System.out.println(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e)); // prints "java.lang.NullPointerException"
        e.printStackTrace(); // prints "java.lang.NullPointerException"
    }
}
```

The output that I would like to see is a full stacktrace with line numbers and the hierarchy of classes that failed. For example,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.Test.myMethod(Test.java:674)
        at org.TestRunner.anotherMethod(TestRunner.java:505)
        at java.util.ArrayList(ArrayList.java:405)
```

This code is being run inside a larger app which also has log4j, but I'm hoping to be able to get the exception into a string so I can send it as an email to the java developers.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can capture the full stack trace to a string? I can't use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() since this app runs on Java 4. What might be blocking the above code from printing the full stacktrace?

Comment: Looks like the StackTraceElement array in NPE is being reset to empty. Is anything calling setStackTrace on the NPE?

Comment: @DanGravell - No, nothing should be calling setStackTrace.

Comment: Are you able to debug this in an IDE? Might be worth setting a breakpoint in the catch block to see if the Exception is 'perfectly formed'.

Comment: add the logged output of your `myMethod()` or your actual method. `e.printStackTrace();` normally should print the fill trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception might be caught and thrown somewhere before your catch block. Maybe in another class which your are calling to do the logic.

An `Exception` created like 
`new Exception(new Throwable("java.lang.NullPointerException"));` 
will print something like what you see.

Comment: It did turn out that inside the try block, that it made a call to another method which had a try block with a catch statement that explicitly reduced the exception (similar to your example except that they didn't hard-code "NullPointerException", but rather just truncated the cause of the stacktrace).

Comment: @David - I would be seriously considering switching to a different product.  Deliberately suppressing exception information like that is going against the best interests of their customers / users.  Find an alternative supplier that doesn't do this kind of crappy thing.

Answer (score 18):

this is beacause java does some code optimiziation when run in server mode (java -server)
to skip this. use `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` in java args
see link below for details:

http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/26/hotspot-caused-exceptions-to-lose-their-stack-traces-in-production-and-the-fix/

Comment: Instead of turning off this optimization on a production server I would just follow Peter's advice and look at an earlier error in the log.

Comment: I agree that can be done when you own the code, if you are dependenty on someone else, till they fix, this is the best you could do.

Comment: This is definitely what caused the similar problem for me on Prod. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: This exists on OpenJDK7 but not on OpenJDK8.

Answer (score 13):

If you repeatedly throw an exception, the JVM stop filling in the stack trace.  I am not sure why but it may be to reduce load on the JVM.  You need to be looking at an earlier stack trace to see the details.

```
for (int n = 0; ; n++) {
    try {
        Integer i = null;
        i.hashCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getStackTrace().length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No more stack trace after " + n + " thrown.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

prints

```
No more stack trace after 20707 thrown.
```

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone have any ideas about how I can capture the full stack trace to a string?

You can use the below way(StringWriter.toString()) to transfer the stack trace into a String.

```
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 e.printStackTrace( new PrintWriter(writer,true ));
 System. out.println("exeption stack is :\n"+writer.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you don't have an appender for console output. You consider adding one. If not, log it as LOGGER.error(ex); with log4j or SLF4J

Comment: For a while, I thought it might be due to console logging. So I tried storing the exception in a string and emailing it to myself. The email only contained "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of 2 reasons why `e.printStackTrace()` might output just the string `"java.lang.NullPointerException"`.

- Something might have called `setStackTrace(new StackTraceElement[0])` on the exception.
- The exception object might be an instance of a tricky class that has overridden the `printStackTrace()` or some other method to return misleading information.

Answer (score 1):

> What might be blocking the above code from printing the full stacktrace?

In my case, a superclass of the `Exception` I was catching had this code:

```
/* avoid the expensive and useless stack trace for API exceptions */
@Override
public Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
    return this;
}
```

This meant that the stack trace array was never filled in so all I got was:

```
org.apache.kafka.AuthException: Auth failed: Invalid username or password
```

with no stack information so no idea *where* it happens.  Lovely.

I was able to override this behavior by grabbing the source for the `Exception`, copying it into my project, and removing the `fillInStackTrace()` method.  It's a hack but I needed information from that `Exception`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you used   e.printStackTrace(), instead of e.getStackTrace();